# Is there a homebrew-cask's "version :latest" and "sha256 :no_check" equivalent for linuxbrew?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask, linuxbrew

There're a lot of formulas like [teamviewer](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/teamviewer.rb) that **have** version number but **NOT** included in its downloading url (as for teamviewer, it is `https://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer.dmg`).

This means, these formulas' upgrading will not reflect on their downloading urls and that will cause an sha256 check failure every time they upgrade.

[homebrew-cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) eliminate this risk by giving `:latest` to `version` and `:no_check` to `sha256`,

```
cask SomeFormula
    version :latest
    sha256 :no_check
    ...
end
```

So that version number is not a concern and sha256 check will be skipped.

What I need is an equivalent mechanism in [linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew).

Does anyone know any related documentation about this? Or any suggestion on how this is achievable in linuxbrew?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of HEAD-only formulas. See [this repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-head-only) for details.

Basically, give it a `head` stanza and nothing else that implies a version. [Example formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-head-only/blob/0cccd5d14c8ed796fab344ded9df5d58d22f6bb3/libphenom.rb):

```
class Libphenom < Formula
  homepage "https://facebook.github.io/libphenom"
  head "https://github.com/facebook/libphenom.git"

  depends_on "libtool" => :build
  depends_on "autoconf" => :build
  depends_on "automake" => :build
  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
  depends_on "openssl"
  depends_on "concurrencykit"

  def install
    system "./autogen.sh"
    system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make"
    system "make", "check"
    system "make", "install"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But HEAD only formula seems a different concept. You see, it is mainly for softwares that have no version numbers (they're always the latest versions corresponding to master branch), but in my case, software has a version number, it is just not reflected on their downloading urls. And, HEAD only formulas are deprecated...

Comment: HEAD-only formulas are not deprecated. That particular tap is, which is very different. HEAD-only formulas are the only way to achieve what you want: if it is not HEAD-only, it will by definition have a version.

Comment: According to [homebrew doc](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md), "Homebrew understands git, svn, and hg URLs, and has a way to specify cvs repositories as a URL as well." so I can't go with this approach.